# Functionality of openreview api to other conferences

Tags: python

I'm trying to get titles of accepted papers in some conferences like ICML, NeurIPS and CVPR. For that, I'm using openreview api (python package). But the problem with that is it doesn't work for NeurIPS 2023, ICML 2023. Also, openreview website doesn't has 2023 CVPR reviews (Though, 2023 being first time CVPR is using openreview). Is there anything I'm not familiar in case of CVPR 2023? However, similar code works for NeurIPS's previous years with change being only the years but not for ICML.

```py
client = openreview.Client(baseurl='https://api.openreview.net')
venue_group = client.get_group('NeurIPS.cc/2023/Conference')
submissions = client.get_all_notes(content={'venueid':'NeurIPS.cc/2023/Conference'} )
submissions
```

Above code gives an empty list for both NeurIPS and ICML. Above code gives Group Not Found  when conference name is replaced with CVPR.

Any help is highly appreciated. I couldn't use appropriate tags for the questions since I couldn't find proper tags.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked on reddit and someone answered [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/18poee4/functionality_of_openreview_api_to_other/). Pasting it here.

> Currently, there are two APIs being maintained but if you want to access conference data from 2023 onwards, you should be using the openreview.api.OpenReviewClient class with the argument baseurl='https://api2.openreview.net'. Also, you don't need to fetch the conference group, it doesn't contain information you need to fetch the submission data.

So, for getting the titles of papers from NeurIPS 2023, you can do:

```py
import openreview

client = openreview.api.OpenReviewClient(baseurl='https://api2.openreview.net')
submissions = client.get_all_notes(content={'venueid':'NeurIPS.cc/2023/Conference'} )
papers_titles = [s.content['title']['value'] for s in submissions]

# checking the first 10 titles
papers_titles[:10]
```

Which gives:

```
['Online PCA in Converging Self-consistent Field Equations',
 'Don’t blame Dataset Shift! Shortcut Learning due to Gradients and Cross Entropy',
 'On Slicing Optimality for Mutual Information',
 'k-Median Clustering via Metric Embedding: Towards Better Initialization with Differential Privacy',
 'Information Maximization Perspective of Orthogonal Matching Pursuit with Applications to Explainable AI',
 'STEVE-1: A Generative Model for Text-to-Behavior in Minecraft',
 'AMAG: Additive, Multiplicative and Adaptive Graph Neural Network For Forecasting Neuron Activity',
 'Conditional Matrix Flows for Gaussian Graphical Models',
 'Representational Strengths and Limitations of Transformers',
 'Cappy: Outperforming and Boosting Large Multi-Task LMs with a Small Scorer']
```

For CVPR 2023 it is probably best to get this information from [their open access site](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/CVPR2023?day=all). You can use XPath to help selecting the titles:

```py
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = 'https://openaccess.thecvf.com/CVPR2023?day=all'
response = fromstring(requests.get(url).text)

# select elements using XPath
elements = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/dl/dt/a/text()')
elements[:10]
```

Which returns:

```
['GFPose: Learning 3D Human Pose Prior With Gradient Fields',
 'CXTrack: Improving 3D Point Cloud Tracking With Contextual Information',
 'Deep Frequency Filtering for Domain Generalization',
 'Frame Flexible Network',
 'Unsupervised Cumulative Domain Adaptation for Foggy Scene Optical Flow',
 'NoisyTwins: Class-Consistent and Diverse Image Generation Through StyleGANs',
 'DisCoScene: Spatially Disentangled Generative Radiance Fields for Controllable 3D-Aware Scene Synthesis',
 'Revisiting Self-Similarity: Structural Embedding for Image Retrieval',
 'Minimizing the Accumulated Trajectory Error To Improve Dataset Distillation',
 'Decoupling-and-Aggregating for Image Exposure Correction']
```